# How to include file rotation in app using objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager, filesize

I have developed an app that basically includes a process to write all `NSLog's`  to a file . And the log is just perfectly written to a file . My question is can I set a limit to the size of the file after which the next file gets created and if Yes , how can I do it.

This is my existing code at beginning of the app delegate .

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Logger.txt"];
NSString *logFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
freopen([logFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
```

Here ,  the `logger.txt` file gets created perfectly , but I want to **limit** the size that a file can hold . I tried searching about it as well but could not find a solution.

Any help would be of great assistance.

Comment: If it's a log file then use [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a function to do the logging activity. Rather than doing file operations each time when you want to log, it is always advisable to create a function for same.

In this function use below code to find size of file.

```
NSDictionary *fileDictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileAttributesAtPath:your_file_path traverseLink:YES];
fileSize = [fileDictionary fileSize];
```

If this fileSize is greater than your allowed size, then rename it with move function of NSFileManager. Create a new file with original name at same location for logging purpose.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear ? I ain't clear with the move function of the NSFileManager @Apurv

Answer (score 0):

```
// example iOS project
// https://github.com/solodyashkin/OSLog

// save source in class to cancel before file will be replaced
dispatch_source_t source = [XClass monitorFileAtPath:path
                                             withEventHandler:^(){

                                                 // fastest way to get file size 
                                                 struct stat st;
                                                 if ( lstat( path.UTF8String, &st ) < 0 )
                                                 {
                                                     // fail to get file size
                                                 }
                                                 else
                                                 {
                                                     // limit to 2MB
                                                     // NSLog(@"log file size in bytes %lld", st.st_size);
                                                     if ( st.st_size > 1024 * 1024 * 2 )
                                                     {
                                                         // TODO:
                                                         // dispatch_source_cancel(source);
                                                         // reopen to new filename
                                                         // or copy log file
                                                         // or ftruncate(STDOUT_FILENO, 0);

                                                         // loop...

                                                     }
                                                 }
                                                                  }
                                                        queue:dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)];
+ (dispatch_source_t)monitorFileAtPath:(NSString*)path withEventHandler:(dispatch_block_t)block queue:(dispatch_queue_t)queue
{
    int fildes = open([path UTF8String], O_EVTONLY);
    dispatch_source_t source = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_VNODE, fildes,
                                                 DISPATCH_VNODE_WRITE | DISPATCH_VNODE_EXTEND,
                                                  queue);
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(source, block);
    dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler(source, ^{
        close(fildes);
    });
    dispatch_resume(source);
    return source;
}
```

Comment: monitoring a file at path, check file size, do what you want (it is not clear what exactly you want to do), variants inside (You can truncate a file when it reaches the limit, .....)

Comment: I have a file in which i write data . I want to create a new file when the file reaches a particular limit and then when the second file reaches that limit , I want  to truncate the file 1 and start writing again . So basically I want to work with two files and keep rotating